# Using policies with azure app registrations vs using policies with azure b2c applications

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Custom Policies on Azure B2C.
When I want to run the Custom Policy I can choose the application which I want to use with the policy. I saw that I'm not only able to use my applications from Azure B2C, I can use the applications from the App Registration section.
What is the differences. I've been able to signup and sign in users with both types of applications.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sets of apps are completely independent of each other.

You should not be able to see any of the Azure AD B2C apps in the Application Registration in Azure Active directory.Also, the apps in the Application Registration should not be visible in the B2C .

In your issue , I assume that you should have add two apps in the two places.

> What is the differences.

**Application in Azure AD B2C** :To build an application that **accepts consumer sign-up and sign-in**, you first need to register the application with an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.

**Application Registration in Azure AD**: This creates an Application ID for the application, and **enables it to receive tokens**. In order to get a client ID and secret from Azure, you have to register the app and provide some basic information about it, including what resources your app wants to access, and what permissions it needs.

Depending on your scenario, you could register an application in both portals, and use the right one depending on the request you need to make.

Comment: Just to add: You can use one app. connected to B2C and authenticate to Azure AD via custom policies. So one app. services users in both portals.

Answer (score 0):

The apps that are registered through each different location (Azure Active AD versus Azure AD B2C) are given credentials that are valid for any policy, including custom policies you have uploaded.

The end result is the same: you have an application that is registered with and can access the policy regardless of how that app/policy was created.